# Confused about what is a block and how local scope works in Ruby

Tags: ruby, scope, block

My understanding is that local variables scope is in the current block, so a looping construct that takes a block defines a new lexical scope, and therefore it's variables are accessible externally, and accordingly one that doesn't, doesn't.

Here is an example that I run on pry:

The loop statement, takes a block and therefore has its own local variables:

```
>loop do
  k = 100
  break
end

>defined? k
# => nil
```

vs a while statement that does not take a block:

```
>while true 
 j = 100
 break
end

>defined? j
# => 'local-variable'
```

Here is what is confusing though, the last statement can also be written as:

```
>while true do 
 j = 100
 break
end

>defined? j

# => 'local-variable'
```

which looks like a block but isn't.

Finally, the following:

```
while true {
 m = 100
 return
}
```

is a syntax error.

My conclusion is that not all do-end blocks are actually blocks and there is no unambiguous way of knowing what defines as lexical scope when reading code other than just knowing it or reading the ruby source code (I still haven't managed to get ri to give me documentation on core ruby..). This maybe something obvious, but I am new to Ruby and would appreciate a rule or something I can read (even if that is the ruby source code), in order to help me read code properly. TIA

Comment: What is `define?`? If you are using non-standard methods, then explain them.

Comment: It is not non-standard. It is a typo. I meant "defined?".

Comment: Why the down vote? Is this an invalid question? (Other than the define typo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion seems to stem from not knowing what exactly a 'block' is.

> My conclusion is that not all do-end blocks are actually blocks

This is true...

> and there is no unambiguous way of knowing what defines as lexical scope when reading code other than just knowing it

...this not so much.

do/end do not a block make. Blocks are defined as being tightly coupled with a method invocation. More concretely, blocks are only legal following a method invocation. 'loop' is a method of class Kernel. 'true' and 'while' are not methods. So the behaviour you are seeing is correct.

Just to make clear: the braces are generally used for blocks that fit on one line, and multi-line blocks are usually delimited between do/end. But if there is no associated method call, do/end does not mean it is a block.

Comment: Thanks Darren for the reply. I am not sure in understand the definition of a block. What I understand from your answer is that there is no specific syntax that uniquely identifies a construct as a block. It would have to be surrounded by a do-end or {}, and be passed to a method. Since loop is a method of Kernel, and `while` is part of the language that would fit the picture, however you will somehow need to know the non-methods as a list. Incidentally I tried the braces on a single line with `while true {n = 100; break;}` and still got a syntax error.

Comment: I could have been clearer. If the braces are used, it is 100% a block. Hence why your example above does not work (no method). The only time do/end ISN'T a block, is when it is used with one of the looping constructs (for, while, until). So a block is anything in braces, and anything in a do/end that is not a `for`, `while`, or `until` loop.

There may be a corner case usage of do/end I have overlooked, but I don't think so.

Comment: This is basically the answer that I need, I just want to know for certain that these are the only expressions that change the meaning of do-end. It certainly seems so from: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html

Comment: @tarzan: Ruby needs to know when the condition part of the `while` loop ends and the loop body begins. There are three ways to tell Ruby that: 1.) a newline, 2.) a semicolon, 3.) the `do` keyword, which in this case is part of the `while` syntax and *not* part of the block literal syntax. Compare with `if`: you can separate the condition from the then-clause by either 1.) newline, 2.) semicolon, 3.) the `then` keyword. In the `while` syntax, the `do` keyword serves the same purpose as the `then` keyword in the `if` syntax: to allow you to write a `while` loop on one line without semicolon.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand the use, but what I find it a little counterintuitive that it looks like a block, but isn't (that is important for variable scope). I am accepting the answer as the explanation is correct and helps people who are learning the language (like me) to understand the difference. Thank you

Comment: @tarzan: well, there's only so many symbols on a keyboard and words in the English language. `{`/`}` are used for `Hash` literals, block literals, and string interpolation, `:` is used for `Symbol` literals, the conditional operator, keyword parameters, keyword arguments, new-style `Hash` literals, and as part of the `::` namespace resolution operator, `.` is used both for message sending and as the decimal separator in `Float` literals, `(`/`)` are used for parameter lists, arguments lists, and expression grouping, `#` is used both for comments and for string interpolation, …

Comment: … `then` is used for `if` expressions, `unless` expressions, and `case` expressions, there are two forms of `if`, two forms of `unless`, two forms of `while`, two forms of `until`, and two forms of `until`, and let's not even talk about the many uses of `end`! Really, `do` having four different uses is not that bad :-D